# Can't call PostgreSQL's 11 Stored Procedure with Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

PostgreSQL 11 now supports stored procedures and I am trying to call one with **Hibernate 5.3.7.Final** and **Postgresql 42.2.5 JDBC driver**.  Previous to PostgreSQL 11 we had functions that could be called with JPA's `@NamedStoredProcedure`. However, the functions were executed with `SELECT my_func();` and the new stored procedures have to be executed with `CALL my_procedure();`

I am trying to execute the following simple stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_raise_wage_employee_older_than(operating_years 
int, raise int)
AS $$
    BEGIN
       UPDATE employees
       SET wage = wage + raise 
       WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM age(entrance_date)) >= operating_years;
    END $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The JPA annotation looks like the following:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "raiseWage", 
   procedureName = "p_raise_wage_employee_older_than", 
   parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "operating_years", type = Integer.class, 
           mode = ParameterMode.IN),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "raise", type = Integer.class, 
            mode = ParameterMode.IN)
})
```

And I am calling the stored procedure with:

```
StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedureQuery = this.em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("raiseWage"); 
storedProcedureQuery.setParameter("operating_years", 20);
storedProcedureQuery.setParameter("raise", 1000);
storedProcedureQuery.execute();
```

My logs look like the following:

```
Hibernate: {call p_raise_wage_employee_older_than(?,?)}
2019-02-17 11:07:41.290  WARN 11168 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42809
2019-02-17 11:07:41.291 ERROR 11168 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: p_raise_wage_employee_older_than(integer, integer) is a procedure
  Hinweis: To call a procedure, use CALL.
  Position: 15
```

The first Hibernate log is indicating that Hibernate uses `call` to execute the stored procedure but I am getting a SQL exception that `CALL` is not used. Is this a bug in the Postgresql dialect as previous to Postgresql 11 you were able to model the `FUNCTIONS` as stored procedures within JPA and therefore `SELECT` was used and not `CALL`?

Comment: Can you use a basic JDBC CallableStatement with one of those? Suggest that you try that since this all a JPA provider is likely using, so it could isolate the problem down to what is different

Comment: As pgJDBC 42.2.5 came out in Aug, 2018 before PostgreSQL 11 (Oct, 2018) I doubt that there is support for the `CALL` syntax in it. The `{call ...}` syntaxt you see in the logs are the JDBC specific one, which sould be translated to the appropriate syntax by the JDBC driver. You probably want to post this [here](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues) as I don't see any relevant issue there. -- For the time being, you could use the "old" way (i.e. define `FUNCTION`s with `RETURNS VOID`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the pgJDBC 42.2.5 was released prior (Aug, 2018) to the PostgreSQL 11 release (Oct, 2018), I think this is currently a issue within the JDBC driver for PostgreSQL itself. I've created a [issue](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/1413) within the GitHub repository.

For a workaround, you could rewrite the `STORED PROCEDURE` as a `FUNCTION` and use `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery` or directly interact with the JDBC `CallableStatement` e.g.:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/", "postgres", "postgres");

CallableStatement callableStatement = conn.prepareCall("{call f_raise_wage_employee_older_than(?,?)}");
callableStatement.setInt(1, 20);
callableStatement.setInt(2, 500);
callableStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Or execute a native query with the `EntityManager`:

```
this.em.createNativeQuery("CALL p_raise_wage_employee_older_than(1, 20)");
```

I'll update this answer as soon as I get an answer from the pgJDBC maintainer.

**UPDATE:**

This topic is already discussed in the Postgres Mailing list (https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4285.1537201440%40sss.pgh.pa.us) and there is currently no solution. The only way is to pass native SQL queries to the database or rewrite the `STORED PROCEDURE` as a `FUNCTION`

Comment: I still have this issue with 42.2.6, did you get an answer?

Comment: I didn‘t check the release notes for this version yet

Answer (score 3):

After PostgreSQL 11, PostgreSQL JDBC driver team has introduced a ENUM name `EscapeSyntaxCallMode` in PostgreSQL driver version 42.2.16. So this enum we can use while creating database connections or creating DataSource object. This Enum has 3 types of Values:

1. "`func`" - set this when we always want to call functions.
2. "`call`" - set this when we always want to call Procedures.
3. "`callIfNoReturn`" - It checks for the return type in calling function/procedure, if return type exists PostgreSQL considers it as a function and calls it as a Function way. Otherwise it calls it as procedure way. So in my project I used this "`callIfNoReturn`", as I wanted PostgreSQL to auto detect whether I am calling function or procedure.

I already have given the answer in detail with the proper steps to follow:

[Postgresql 11: Stored Procedure call error - To call a procedure, use CALL, Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65696904/postgresql-11-stored-procedure-call-error-to-call-a-procedure-use-call-java)

Comment: thanks a lot for taking the time to also add the answer to this question

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. This is my solution.

```
try {
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("CALL procedure( :param1, :param2 )");
    query.setParameter("param1", intParam1);
    query.setParameter("param2", intParam2);
    
    log.info("Running...");
    try {
        query.getSingleResult();
    } catch (PersistenceException pe) {
        if (pe.getCause() != null && pe.getCause() instanceof GenericJDBCException) {
            GenericJDBCException gjdbce = (GenericJDBCException) pe.getCause();
            // NO_RESULTS_CODE = "02000" in PostgreSQL
            if (NO_RESULTS_CODE.equals(gjdbce.getSQLState())) {
                log.info("Success!");
                return;
            }
        }
        
        throw pe;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

Good luck!