# Can I call Postgres stored procedure utilizing Spring SimpleJdbcCall

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, spring-jdbc, simplejdbccall

I got below error when I call postgres stored procedure by utilizing spring's SimpleJdbcCall.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback; 
bad SQL grammar [{call myProc(?, ?)}]; 
nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: myProc(numeric, character varying) is a procedure
  Hint: To call a procedure, use CALL.
```

It seems to me that postgres jdbc driver interprets the procedure as funtion. Does anyone have any idea?

Followings are SP and java code (jdk8 and tomcat are used)

stored procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myProc(
     INOUT p_errcode    numeric,
     INOUT p_errmessage character varying
)
```

db url

jdbc:postgresql://host:5432/sid?escapeSyntaxCallMode=call

maven dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
   <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
   <version>42.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

java code snippets

```
SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(template)
   .withProcedureName(procName)
   .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess();

simpleJdbcCall.setAccessCallParameterMetaData(false);
simpleJdbcCall.declareParameters(
   new SqlInOutParameter("p_errcode", Types.NUMERIC),
   new SqlInOutParameter("p_errmessage", Types.VARCHAR)
);
                     
SqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource()
   .addValue("p_errcode ", 0)
   .addValue("p_errmessage ", "error");

try {
   Map<String, Object> simpleJdbcCallResult = simpleJdbcCall.execute(parameters);
   ... ... ...
```

Comment: Have you looked at docs here [Calling functions/procedures](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/callproc/): *Example 6.5. Calling a stored procedure*

Comment: I'd like to know if it is possible to use spring SimpleJdbcCall to invoke postgres SP. If not, I will switch to use JDBC PreparedStatement.

Comment: Try escapeSyntaxCallMode=callIfNoReturn, see [procedure-call-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65696904/postgresql-11-stored-procedure-call-error-to-call-a-procedure-use-call-java)