# Postgres DB - Using JPA StoredProcedureQuery invoke Stored Procedure in Postgres DB which has OUT Parameter as Ref Cursor

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, stored-procedures, postgres-14

Please do not confuse this with Function, its specifically for Stored Procedure.

Need to call a Stored Procedure in Postgres DB using JPA's StoredProcedureQuery. Stored Procedure has OUT parameter as REF Cursor.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_sub_procedure(
    OUT sub_proc_ref_cursor REFCURSOR,
    IN sub_proc_desc_text varchar
)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
DECLARE
    dummy_test timestamp;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE_TEST_REF_CURSOR
    VALUES (sub_proc_desc_text);
    OPEN sub_proc_ref_cursor FOR SELECT * FROM TEMP_TABLE_TEST_REF_CURSOR;
END;
$$;
```

When calling from JPA like this

```
    StoredProcedureQuery query = session.createStoredProcedureQuery("test_sub_procedure");
    query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, void.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);
    query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    query.setParameter(2, "from java jpa code");
//            List<Object[]> postComments = query.getResultList();
    query.execute();
    ResultSet resultSet = (ResultSet) query.getOutputParameterValue(1);
```

Getting error

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.execute(ProcedureCallImpl.java:622)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.convert(OutputsImpl.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.<init>(OutputsImpl.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureOutputsImpl.<init>(ProcedureOutputsImpl.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.buildOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:416)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.outputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:632)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.execute(ProcedureCallImpl.java:615)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: test_sub_procedure(character varying) is a procedure
  Hint: To call a procedure, use CALL.
  Position: 15
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2675)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2365)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:355)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:490)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:408)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:166)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgCallableStatement.executeWithFlags(PgCallableStatement.java:83)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.execute(PgPreparedStatement.java:155)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyCallableStatement.execute(NewProxyCallableStatement.java:3214)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.<init>(OutputsImpl.java:56)
    ... 7 more
```

**EDIT :**
So what is happening is, its trying to call Function Way.
When I added `?escapeSyntaxCallMode=call` it was forced to call it in Procedure Way and it worked. But when I am using `?escapeSyntaxCallMode=callIfNoReturn` it it thinking its a function and failing

Why is it thinking of it as Function and not Procedure?

Reference : [Postgresql 11: Stored Procedure call error - To call a procedure, use CALL, Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65696904/postgresql-11-stored-procedure-call-error-to-call-a-procedure-use-call-java)

Is there any way to specifically set `?escapeSyntaxCallMode=call` to StoredProcedureQuery Object

Comment: and what should jpa do with a refcursor? why not return the row it self or the uniue id?

Comment: its just an example, but I want to do it for more than one row where REF CURSOR is required

Comment: When I am printing Hibernate Show SQL logs
{? = call test_sub_procedure(?)}
Which looks like function call and not procedure call

Comment: Why do you want a refcursor, as far as I can tell no driver can do that, can you elaborate what you need the refcursor in jpa for